# What is the proper syntax for pinning a debian package to a repository and a version?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I am trying to install a previous version of subversion from snapshot.debian.org, as described in [How to install the previous version of a .deb package and pin it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242014/how-to-install-the-previous-version-of-a-deb-package-and-pin-it). I have setup the repository and the pinning as I believe to be correct, but it is not working as I expected, as the `apt-cache-policy` output shows. Where are the errors in it?

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/snapshots.list`

```
# snapshots.debian.org                                          
# added for subversion 1.9.2 subversion bug #803725             
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian unstable main
```

`/etc/apt/preferences.d/subversion`

```
Package: subversion
Pin: origin snapshot.debian.org
Pin: version 1.9.2-1
Pin-Priority: 700
```

`apt-cache policy subversion`

```
subversion:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.2-3
  Package pin: (not found)
  Version table:
     1.9.2-3 700
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Thomas Dickey's answer may have provided a working solution, but I'd like to know if there's an answer to the question posed in the title.  i.e. can you base a pin on both the origin and the version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you cannot use snapshot.debian.org directly as a source of packages.  To see this, select a URL from that site as the source in sources.list, e.g.,

```
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20151018T155352Z/ testing main
deb-src http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20151018T155352Z/ testing main
```

(commenting out the other settings), and doing

```
apt-get update
```

to force it to use *only* that source (as done in [*Downgrade and force some packages on Debian to a previous version*](http://hackedbellini.org/linux/downgrade-and-force-some-packages-on-debian-to-a-previous-version/)).  When I do this, I get

```
$ apt-get update
Hit http://snapshot.debian.org testing InRelease
E: Release file for http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20151018T155352Z/dists/testing/InRelease is expired (invalid since 16d 9h 47min 8s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

That was the last snapshot before 1.9.2-2 was released.  Instead, found in a mailing list reply *[Re: Plasma 5 doesn't start after update on Stretch](https://lists.debian.org/debian-kde/2015/08/msg00140.html)* by Matthias Bodenbinder, he suggested

- downloading the specific version needed
- install the package, i.e., using `dpkg`
- *pin* the (now-installed) package (his example uses no *origin*).

To test the instructions, I used these links from the initial release of subversion_1.9.1-1:

- [subversion_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20150924T154447Z/pool/main/s/subversion/subversion_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb)
- [subversion-tools_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20150924T154447Z/pool/main/s/subversion/subversion-tools_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb)
- [libsvn1_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20150924T154447Z/pool/main/s/subversion/libsvn1_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb)

and installed them:

```
$ dpkg -i libsvn1_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb subversion-tools_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb subversion_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb
dpkg: warning: downgrading libsvn1:amd64 from 1.9.2-2 to 1.9.1-1
(Reading database ... 371500 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libsvn1_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsvn1:amd64 (1.9.1-1) over (1.9.2-2) ...
Preparing to unpack subversion-tools_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking subversion-tools (1.9.1-1) over (1.9.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack subversion_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking subversion (1.9.1-1) over (1.9.1-1) ...
Setting up libsvn1:amd64 (1.9.1-1) ...
Setting up subversion (1.9.1-1) ...
Setting up subversion-tools (1.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-22) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
```

Then (in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/subversion`):

```
Package: libsvn1
Pin: version 1.9.1-1
Pin-Priority: 1000

Package: subversion-tools
Pin: version 1.9.1-1
Pin-Priority: 1000

Package: subversion
Pin: version 1.9.1-1
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

and finally

```
$ apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing-updates,n=stretch-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
Pinned packages:
     subversion -> 1.9.1-1
     libsvn1 -> 1.9.1-1
     subversion-tools -> 1.9.1-1
```

Comment: Have you tried [echo "Acquire::Check-Valid-Until \"false\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/check-valid-until.conf](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt.conf.5.en.html#THE_ACQUIRE_GROUP)?